# can not read from xml file. call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, xml

I have the following code that must read xml data from a database from different servers.

```
foreach($servers->result() as $server){
    $srvr = $server->ip;
    $loading_server = "http://".$srvr."/status.xml";
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $status = $doc->load($loading_server);
    $power_out = $status->getElementsByTagName( "input0" );
    $temperature = $status->getElementsByTagName( "input1" );
    $rf_antenna_power = $status->getElementsByTagName( "input2" );
    echo "<b>$srvr: $power_out - $temperature - $rf_antenna_power \n</b><br>";
}
```

each server has got a status report in a `status.xml` file which is something like this:

```
<response>
<input0>1</input0>
<input1>0</input1>
<input2>0</input2>
<input3>0</input3>
<input4>0</input4>
...
..
<response>
```

But I get the bellow error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\transmitter\application\views\body.php on line 10
```

I thought of using `$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($wrss));` to access the xml content but yet I cant and get the warning:

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag response invalid in Entity
```

Please help me in this!

Comment: When this happens, something has gone wrong at some point - either when loading the entire file, or when searching for a specific tag. In your case, it seems like you're not closing `<response>` properly

Comment: Are you sure you need to create object for each `result()` ?

Comment: @Pekka, That closing `<response>` tag is my typo in the post. It is correct in my code!

Comment: @Charlie, There are about 10 servers with their status.xml files, so I thought I need to do that. is this a wrong approch?

Comment: that's just feels not eficient. bad practice may be. If I were you, I'll put `$doc = new DOMDocument();` outside the `foreach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DomDocument::load return only bool in non-static call: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php

Right using to example:

```
if ($status){
    $doc->getElementsByTagName( "input0" );
}
```